# python glob module requiring quotes on argv

Tags: python, glob, argv

What's the problem with test.py code?

```
$ ls *csv
test1.csv test2.csv test3.csv test4.csv
$ python test.py *csv
test1.csv
$ python test.py '*csv'
test1.csv
test2.csv
test3.csv
test4.csv
$ cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys,glob

for filename in glob.glob(sys.argv[1]):
    print filename
$
```

Ultimately I want not to be forced to pass arguments to the script with quotes.

**EDIT: found the problem after comments on the accepted answer**

If shell expansion works, I don't have to use glob, so the loop is:

```
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    print filename
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is nearly right - you probably don't want to include sys.argv[0] which will be your script name, so I'd use "for filename in sys.argv[1:]".

Comment: oh, you're right, I'll edit again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't anything specific to `glob` or Python, it's just how wildcards work in the shell. You can see this by replacing your script with one that just does:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

In the first example, the `*.csv` is expanded into multiple filenames by the shell before your script runs. You can see this by printing `sys.argv` - all of the matching filenames will be in there.

If you don't want the shell to expand wildcards then you need to quote or escape them using `\`. (There is one corner case here - bash will pass `*.csv` in to your script if there are no files that match. zsh will signal an error in this case by default.)

Apparently you can turn off glob expansion in the shell with:

```
set -f
```

But I don't think that's what you want.

Lots of information about expansion [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs).

Comment: Try printing sys.argv - you'll see that it has all of test[1-4].csv in there. sys.argv[1] is test1.csv, so that's what's being passed into glob.glob, and that's all that's being returned.